# XmlHttpRequest to nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send XMLHttpRequest from client side js to my node server. But nothing is happening. I'm quite new to this stuff. This is my function in javascript.

```
function sendTokenToServer(token) {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
   // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
   console.log(xhttp.responseText);
} 
xhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/", true);
xtthp.send();
};
}
```

And this is my route in node js

```
    app.get('/fcm', function(req, res) {

      console.log('here');
      res.end('hee');
    });
```

Comment: found the solution. I was calling send in onreadystatechange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't making a request to the endpoint you created, you are requesting the route: `/` (which may or may not exist). Change the request to

```
 xhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/fcm", true);
```

And it should work (assuming your webpage and the server are running on the same port, otherwise you could run into CORS issues).

Comment: It worked! I called send() function in call back. Just wasted and hour.